# Chain few CompletableFuture operations

Tags: java, completable-future

I have few separate operations that i want to chain in the same style like we have for `Promises` in JS.

So currently i have such code:

```
    CompletableFuture<Data1> data1 = ...;
    CompletableFuture<Data2> data2 = ...;

    // Fetch in parallel!
    CompletableFuture.allOf(
            data1,
            data2
    ).join(); // wait 2 threads to finish

    CompletableFuture<Data3> data3 = ... // i need data1 here
    data3.join();
```

Is it possible to rewrite it in one chain ?
Kind of:

```
CompletableFuture.allOf(
        data1,
        data2
)
.then((result1, result2) -> return another CompletableFuture)
.then(result3 -> { ...do other stuff here})
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `allOf`, there is no way around calling `join` on the input futures to get the values in a dependent function (though you’ll know that these calls won’t block).

However, when you have exactly two futures to combine, there is no need to use `allOf`; you can combine them smoothly:

```
CompletableFuture<FinalResult> f = data1
    .thenCombine(data2, (result1, result2) -> another CompletableFuture)
    .thenCompose(Function.identity())
    .thenAccept(result3 -> …);
```

`thenAccept` will evaluate a function mapping a result value to a new result value, whereas `thenCompose` will evaluate a function mapping a result value to a new future. The method `thenCombine` is the two-future variant of `thenAccept`, allowing to map two values to a new value.

But there is no two-future variant of `thenCombine`, so the solution is to treat the future created from the two intermediate values like a value (getting a future of a future), followed by `thenCompose(Function.identity())` to map the “value” to a future. Then, we can chain a function for processing the third result, once the future has been completed.

Answer (score 0):

[`CompletableFuture.allOf(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf(java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...)) returns a  `CompletableFuture<Void>`. It knows nothing about the types that will be returned by the givne `CompletableFuture`s:

> the results, if any, of the given `CompletableFuture`s are not reflected in the returned `CompletableFuture`, but may be obtained by inspecting them individually.

So you will have to `get` the returned values of `data1` and `data2` if you want to use them.